# Anti-aliasing CSS Input Top Border

Tags: css

I am not sure if I use the right word "anti-aliasing" here. Please refer to below CSS and images gathered from laptop web browser and iPhone mobile browser.

```
input {
  font-size: 1rem;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.8rem 0.7rem;
  color: gray;
}
```

Btw Android mobile browser working fine.

[This is from laptop web browser. Top border is sharp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhK2v.png)

[This is from iPhone mobile web browser. Top border isn't sharp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GplH3.png)

Comment: Looks like a `box-shadow`. Did you try `box-shadow: none`?

Comment: I added box-shadow: none, no impact.